# Hide phone update notifications

Tags: update, insider-preview, lumia-520

A few days ago I installed Windows Insider (on my Lumia 521) and chose the Fast Track. So now I have a phone update that's ready to download. (I've unchecked "Automatically download updates if my data settings allow it".)

But I don't want to download and install the update. I used Windows Insider intending to get Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2 (following the instructions [here](http://wmpoweruser.com/windows-insider-app-delivers-windows-phone-8-1-update-2-to-any-handset-which-does-not-support-w10m-tp/)), but it looks like the update will be Windows 10. I don't want to install Windows 10, because it's supposed to be slow as molasses. I've since uninstalled Windows Insider.

I'm periodically getting notifications that an update is available. How do I disable these notifications (or the update that's ready to download)? I don't see an option for disabling the update notifications in notifications+actions.

Comment: There was an update pushed out to Windows Phones "recently", so it is *possible* that is the update you're seeing

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather nuclear option, but presumably you could:

1. back up your phone (Settings > Backup > Apps+Settings, press Back up now)
2. install the update
3. downgrade with [Windows Phone Recovery Tool](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-recovery-tool-windows-10-technical-preview-phones)
4. restore from your backup

Comment: Not sure you would need to install the update - you should be able to just run the Windows Phone Recovery Toolkit without installing Windows 10 fist, right? Still nuclear, bit a bit less ;-)

Comment: Put that way, I could probably just do a plain factory reset and restore.