# Turn off "An update is ready for download" notification

Tags: update, notifications

It appears there is no answer to this one, as there is a prior unanswered question [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9828/hide-phone-update-notifications), but I want to make a clearer go at this:

I do not want to update to Windows 8.1. I keep getting a notification *every day* saying "An update is ready for download." I do not want this update and I have used Windows Phone 8.1 and I prefer 8.0 for one because everything is faster.

If I ever want to update in the future, I can go into `Settings:about` anyway, so I do not need this notification.

So I want to get rid of it or even reduce its frequency. Is there a way?

Comment: AFAIK the only way would be to take it offline. Obviously that's not really a good solution. But on the other hand, staying on an outdated and unsupported OS isn't a good idea, either.